# Where can I ask questions about the history of a result?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, se-sites

I would like to know when a particular definition for a mathematical object was reformulated into the new version.  Is there a place on stack exchange for this?

If not, then where would I go for this info?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't see why you would not ask this here.

Comment: *Here*, of course, means *there*, the main math site.

Comment: Well, its not a problem to be solved like prove this or that or something so I wasnt sure, but thanks.

Comment: @JasonSmith: For an example, see this question I had asked: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16946/history-of-show-that-44-dots-88-dots-9-is-a-perfect-square

Answer (score 7):

To add to Mariano's answer, keep in mind that there is a tag for math history questions: [math-history](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math-history).

Answer (score 7):

You may ask questions about the history of mathematics at [History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/), which is currently in beta.